# OpenX: Deactivated Banners to shown in Zone

Tags: php, timezone, openx, adbannerview

I have created one Compaign (**Ad1_Compaign**), and i have put **two banners** to that Compaign (Ad1_Compaign).
And I have **linked** these 2 banners(***Banner1 and Banner2***) to one Zone under one Website.

After that, I am running the Invocation Code for that Zone, it displays with good (both banners are displaying randomly).

I have two doubts.

Doubt I:

> How many times once change the banner everytime page re-loading? How
>   to measure that?...

Then After I deactivated the Banner1 means, In **Zone->Linked Banners** shows good with Inactive Banner.

But generating the Zone Code the Banner1 is also displayed... But it is deactivated...

Doubt II:

> How to display only Active Banners only in Zone?

Anyone Please Help me...

Comment: Kindly give clarity to your question and to the point... would love to help if can understand your question!

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan I am `using OpenX Ad Server`. I have created **2 Banners(Banner1 and Banner2)** under the **Compaign (Ad1_Compaign)**. Generating the Compaign(Ad1_Compaign) Code from _"Direct Selection"_ option, The code runs with good both banners randomly displayed. If I deactivate **Banner1** from _"Banners"_ option and generating code again from _"Direct Selection"_ , now too displays with both banners(Banner1 and Banner2). But 'Banner1' is deactivated now... `How to display only Active Banners only?...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of times the banner appears can be controlled from the "banner properties" section in OpenX.

The deactivated banner is showing up because of the OpenX cache. (It is set by default to 1200 secs i.e 20 mins)

If you have admin access to OpenX, you can reset this cache period to a smaller value.

If you want to delete the existing cache immediately, then you should go to the server where OpenX is installed and delete the contents of openx/var/cache inside the openx folder (i.e where openx is installed)